# Scrolling with indexbar in a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, indexing, scroll

I got a table view with approx 45k items. I want to use the indexbar to be able to scroll faster through my list.

Now I've looked at other questions on here, but I just can't figure out what to do.

I've got the following two functions:

```
-(NSArray*)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return alphabetsArray;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {


    return index;
}
```

I don't understand what I should do next. Like, I have an array called airports which is sorted alphabetically. What should I be doing with this array?

**update**

so I found an article I could use and I'm pretty close now, I think. My table view only shows 2 items now though.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"ROWS METHOD CALLED");
    NSArray *unsortedKeys = [alphabetizedAirports allKeys];
    NSArray *sortedKeys = [unsortedKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];


    NSString *key = [sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *airportsForSection = [alphabetizedAirports objectForKey:key];


    return [airportsForSection count];

}
```

I have about 60 items in my sortedKeys array. The airportsForSection array only gets 2 items though so when it returns the array, the tableview only shows 2 items. Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: Look at the "TheElements" sample app.

Comment: I had already looked at it, but I just looked at it again and still don't see how I can use it for my project. Maybe I'm just tired..

Comment: You need to partition your data into sections and setup a sectioned table view.

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/table-view-basics/   I followed this article and managed to make sections. However I'm only getting 2 items now. I've updated my question with some code..